# UIScrollView stopped scrolling after adding an ImageView in parent view?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uiscrollview

I have a `UIScrollView` in my main view. It was working fine. The `UIScrollView` stopped scrolling when I added a `UIImageView` on top of that scroll view.But it is working fine if I remove the `UIImageView`. The purpose of `UIImageView` is to give a background image for the main view.

The view hierarchy is

- Parent View

  - Background `UIImageView`
  - `UIScrollView`

[image]

I have added following code in viewDidLoad function:

```
_scrollView.contentSize = self.view.frame.size;
_scrollView.frame = self.view.frame;
[self.view addSubview:_scrollView];
[self.view bringSubviewToFront:_scrollView];
```

Comment: show us the screenshot of app and storyboard it will help us to help you

Comment: Are you adding the image view programmatically?  If yes, chances are that your Imageview is added above the scrollview and scrollview is not receiving any input so it is not scrolling. Provide the code of how you are adding it or it will be a lot  harder to reach a conclusion.

Comment: Hi, I have added the screen shot and code snippet

Comment: Hi, I have added the screen shot and code snippet

Comment: @kunjus I have posted an answer. I hope that will fix your issue

Comment: @kunjus Have you tested it yet? If it solved your problem please mark it as correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

After you add image view add this line . I assume both you scrollview and image are added in main view.

```
[self.view bringSubviewToFront:yourscrollview]
```

and set you scrollview background color to clearcolor so image background is visible.

Comment: That is my guess as well. He is saying he is adding imageview on top of scrollview but does not mention how  he is doing it. Then in hierarchy he says imageview is below scrollview. A bit too hasty to post the answer without seeing the code first,don't you think?

Comment: He mentioned 
MainView -BackgroundImage View -ScrollView

Comment: @Imran, read the question. He says he is adding Imageview on top of scrollview

Comment: Yes but he also mentioned the view structure that's why I wrote in my answer * I assume both you scrollview and image are added in main view*

Comment: @Imran all the more reason to be patient until you don't have to make assumptions. Which will be when he clarifies.  But anyways. Whatever you like.

Comment: I have modified the question and added the screen shot

Answer (score 0):

You are setting `ContentSize` of the `UIScrollView` wrong on following lines:

```
_scrollView.contentSize = self.view.frame.size;
_scrollView.frame = self.view.frame;
```

If it is equal to its own size, it won't scroll. Give it a content size which is greater than that. 
Do Something like this for testing:

```
_scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(self.view.frame.size.width, 1000);
```

Also why are you adding the _scrollView as a subview again? It is already added in the view through xib file. Are you re-adding the background `UIImageView` as well in your code? if yes, that will cause more problems for you. Get rid of redundant manual addition of subviews.

Comment: to the guys who posted irrelevant and wrong answer,  who got downvoted for it, I just want to say revenge downvoting is really pathetic. If it makes you feel any better, it was not me who downvoted your answer. It is almost funny that you are downvoting a correct answer just to get back at somebody

Answer (score 0):

Your scrollView's contentSize should have a larger frame than your scrollview's basic frame,otherwise, it would not scroll,it means that you did not leave enough space for scrollView scrolling to display.

Answer (score 0):

In xib, your need to tell the xib the ContentSize of your ScrollView. If you have give it the leading space, trailing space, top space, and bottom space, you just have told the super view your ContentSize, So you need give him the width constraint and height constraint also, then the super view will know your actual frame; if the height or the width is larger than the ContentSize, it will scroll.